# Should I unset both `$key` and `$value` after every foreach statement?

Tags: php, foreach, unset

All the answers I've found only talk about unsetting `$value` except one, which wasn't clear to me.  So here I am. Say I have the line:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
    // do stuff
    }
```

Should I put these two lines after?

```
unset($key);
unset($value);
```

Or can I omit `unset($key)`?  Also, is it recommended to ALWAYS use unset after every `foreach`?  Say I have nested `foreach` loops, like this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach ($data[$key] as $key => $value)
        {
        // do stuff
        }
        unset($key);
        unset($value);
    }
    unset($key);
    unset($value);
```

Would the nested `unset()` functions interfere with the highest level `foreach`?  In other words, are the nested `$key` and `$value` the same as the highest level `$key` and `$value`?

Comment: There's no *need* to unset either. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using a `foreach` loop to create an array of keys with unique values but some keys are getting assigned the same values as keys created before them in an unpredictable manner, and I don't have a single `unset()` in my entire code so I was suspecting that was why.

Comment: Just use different variables for the nested foreach loop. `foreach($data as $k => $v)`

Comment: The only common disadvantage of not calling `unset` after a loop is if you're looping over by reference, which you aren't. Otherwise, the variables either get overwritten with something else, or they just fall out of scope. If you're using the same variable names in nested loops, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks @GrumpCrouton, that seems like an easy fix.  Thanks.

Comment: @iainn, are you saying I do NOT need to use `unset`?  Sorry I'm having trouble understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is easier than you think it is.

Simply change the variable names for your nested loop, like so:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

With the above code, you can access the array data from `$date[$key]` (Which is actually equal to `$value` inside the parent loop) as `$subkey` and `$subvalue` respectively.

You can also still access the parent loop data anywhere inside the parent foreach loop with `$key` and `$value` respectively.